# Subprocess return code different than "echo $?"

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I'm using subprocess to call a bash command in Python, and I'm getting a different return code than what the shell shows me.

```
import subprocess
def check_code(cmd):
    print "received command '%s'" % (cmd)
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    p.wait()
    print "p.returncode is '%d'" % (p.returncode)
    exit()
    if p.returncode == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    #End if there was a return code at all
#End get_code()
```

When sent "ls /dev/dsk &> /dev/null", check_code returns 0, but "echo $?" produces "2" in the terminal:

```
Welcome to Dana version 0.7
Now there is Dana AND ZOL

received command 'ls /dev/dsk &> /dev/null'
p.returncode is '0'
root@Ubuntu-14:~# ls /dev/dsk &> /dev/null
root@Ubuntu-14:~# echo $?
2
root@Ubuntu-14:~#
```

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: I think you're seeing the shell's return code, not that of `ls`.

Comment: Is the return value of `p.wait()` also incorrect?

Comment: Keep in mind that it's not recommended to use `shell=True`. Especially with untrusted user input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), the shell used in your Python script is `sh`. This shell is the POSIX standard, as opposed to Bash, which has several nonstandard features such as the shorthand redirection `&> /dev/null`. `sh`, the Bourne shell, interprets this symbol as "run me in the background, and redirect stdout to /dev/null".

Since your `subprocess.Popen` opens a `sh` which runs `ls` in its own background, the return value of `sh` is used instead of `ls`, which in this case is 0.

If you want Bash behavior with your Python, I believe you may have to reconfigure (possibly recompile) Python itself. It's simpler to just use the `sh` syntax, which is `ls /dev/dsk 2> /dev/null`.

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestion by xi_, I split the command up in to space delineated fields, and it failed to run with "&>" and "/dev/null".  I removed them, and it worked.

Then I put the command all back together to test it without "&> /dev/null", and that worked too.  It appears that the addition of "&> /dev/null" throws subprocess off, somehow.

```
Welcome to Dana version 0.7
Now there is Dana AND ZOL

received command 'cat /etc/fstab'
p.wait() is 0
p.returncode is '0'

received command 'cat /etc/fstabb'
p.wait() is 1
p.returncode is '1'

received command 'cat /etc/fstab &> /dev/null'
p.wait() is 0
p.returncode is '0'

received command 'cat /etc/fstabb &> /dev/null'
p.wait() is 0
p.returncode is '0'
root@Ubuntu-14:~# cat /etc/fstab &> /dev/null
root@Ubuntu-14:~# echo $?
0
root@Ubuntu-14:~# cat /etc/fstabb &> /dev/null
root@Ubuntu-14:~# echo $?
1
root@Ubuntu-14:~#
```

I originally added the "&> /dev/null" to the call because I was seeing output on the screen from STDERR.  Once I added stderr=PIPE to the subprocess call, that went away.  I was just trying to silently check the code on the output behind the scenes.

If someone can explain why adding "&> /dev/null" to a subprocess call in Python causes it to behave unexpectedly, I'd be happy to select that as the answer!

Comment: We're using bash as a shell, but python uses `sh` which interprets `&>` differently from bash.

Answer (score -1):

You are using it as `subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)`, with `cmd` as string.

That means that subprocess will call under the hood `/bin/sh` with arguments. So you are getting back exit code of your `shell`.

If you need actually exit code of your command, split it into list and use `shell=False`.

`subprocess.Popen(['cmd', 'arg1'], shell=False)`

Comment: You can't avoid the shell if you need `&>/dev/null` though. Also the exit code of the shell should be the exit code of the last command that was run.